# Python 3.x thread hanging on join() call

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, thread-safety

I'm having trouble with a thread hanging when I call join() on it. What I am trying to do is use the Go-back N protocol for sending/receiving packets over a network, and I created a separate thread for handling the ACK's that come back from the server.

I have a single thread run on this method that checks for incoming packets and retrieves the ACK number, then stores that number in a variable set-up in the **init** called `self.lastAck`. Simplified version of the method:

```py
    #Anything not explicitly defined here is global variable
    def ack_check(self):
        ack_num = 0
        pktHdrData = '!BBBBHHLLQQLL'
        # Listening for ack number from server and store it in self.lastAck.
        while True:
            # variable also inside the __init__ method
            if (self.finish == 1):
                break
            data,address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
            clientAck = struct.unpack(pktHdrData,data)
            ackNumRecv = clientAck[9]
            self.lastAck = ackNumRecv
```

A simplified version of the function that creates the thread and handles the sending of the client packets:

```py
    def send(self,buffer):

        # Assume packet header and all relevant data is set up correctly here
        # ...

        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.ack_check, args=())
        t1.setDaemon = True
        t1.start()

        # All of this works perfectly and breaks as expected
        while True:
            # Packets/data get sent here and break when self.lastAck reaches a specific number. Assume this works properly and breaks


        self.finish = 1
        print("About to hang here")
        t1.join()
        return bytessent
```

I end up hanging right after printing the `About to end here` and I can't figure out why. I can get it to work if I break out of the `while True` loop in the `else` section, but then I end up closing the thread before I receive all the ACK numbers from the receiver. So instead of the full 32 ACK's I'll end up with anywhere from 1 ACK to the full 32.

I think the problem lies in the `def ack_check(self)` method where it doesn't break out of the loop even though it should be after I call `self.finish = 1` but it just ends up hanging every time.

Additionally there is nothing else outside of these two methods that are calling self.finish and self.lastAck. I know about deadlocking but I couldn't see how that would be possible in this situation.

Sidenote: I realize the Go-Back N protocol is not properly implemented at all here, but this was the first step I took in creating it.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. There's way too much guessing here. Anyhow, `join()` waits for the thread to terminate of its own, maybe that's your misunderstanding.

Comment: You have a `recvfrom` in the loop for `ack_check`, your thread might be stuck there so it never reaches the `self.finish == 1` check so that it knows to exit.

Comment: You could do some printf-Debugging on `ack_check` to see where it gets stuck. My guess is that your receiving nothing on your socket anymore but you still are waiting for data to arrive at `recvfrom`, and since you probably didn't specify a timeout for the socket it will never return from `recvfrom`.

Comment: That was indeed the solution. I added a timeout to the recv call and did a try/except on it. Fully working now, I'll update the post with this solution

Comment: @WilliamJones Instead of updating the question with the solution, answer your own question below where it can be upvoted.  You can accept it as the best answer as well, even if it is your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the recvfrom call in ack_check left the thread hanging. Fixed code:

```py
    def ack_check(self):
        ack_num = 0
        pktHdrData = '!BBBBHHLLQQLL'
        # Listening for ack number from server and store it in self.lastAck.
        while True:
            # variable also inside the __init__ method
            if (self.finish == 1):
                break
            sock.timeout(0.2)
            try:
                data,address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
            except socket.timeout:
                break
            clientAck = struct.unpack(pktHdrData,data)
            ackNumRecv = clientAck[9]
            self.lastAck = ackNumRecv
```